# Iterating over pyshp writer object records

Tags: shapefile, pyshp

The current branch of [pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) has removed the Editor class that combines reading and writing records. The justification is that [removing the Editor has been planned for a while now, and might as well remove along with the other major new changes](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp/commit/02d8a4442b9353ffa5254a559a1500ccd72aa4cb). Is there any way I can call a `shapefile.Writer` object and invoke  a `records()` type functionality that lists all present records in the writer object?
The only records introspection in pyshp currently is the `.shpNum` property that is just an incrementor:

```
def __dbfRecord(self, record):
    """Writes the dbf records."""
    f = self.__getFileObj(self._dbf)
    self.recNum += 1
```